# getting 500 internal server error while saving data from vue form laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, vuex

when i click on the button to save the data from the form i get the error 500 internal server error am using a laravel backend where i have written the function to save the data from the form to the DB

```
<template>
<form>
          <div>
    <input  type="text" v-model="contact.first_name" placeholder="Enter first name">
    </div>
    ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                contact:{},
            }
        },
        methods: {
            createContact(contact) {
                this.$store.dispatch('createContact', this.contact);
                this.contact = '';
                alert('A contact has been added!')
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

This is my store.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios'


Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
       contacts: [],
    },


   
    mutations: {
        CREATE_CONTACT(state, contact) {
            state.contacts.unshift(contact)
        },
       
    },

    actions: {
        createContact({commit}, contact) {
            console.log(contact);
            axios.post('/api/contacts', contact)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    commit('CREATE_CONTACT', res.data)
                }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },
     
    }


});import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from 'axios'


Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
       contacts: [],
    },


   
    mutations: {
        CREATE_CONTACT(state, contact) {
            state.contacts.unshift(contact)
        },
       
    },

    actions: {
        createContact({commit}, contact) {
            console.log(contact);
            axios.post('/api/contacts', contact)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    commit('CREATE_CONTACT', res.data)
                }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },
     
    }
```

});

This is my controller where i have written the function store that contains the functionality to store data in the database
public function store(Request $request)
{

```
    $contact = Contact::create($request->all());
    
  
    return response()->json(['result'=>$contact]);
    
}
```

Comment: And what's that 500 says ?

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: You can find a more detailled message in your laravel.log file..

Comment: or set debug=true in .env file

Comment: thanks got the error and fixed it